# Django/Python check if key exists and then conditionally change the value of key in efficient and pythonic way

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I want to check if key exists in `request.query_params` and if it does then I'm checking the value, if it's having `'t'` then changing it to boolean `True` else `False`. Below is the code I wrote but it looks bad, is there a [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and efficient way?

```
# [...]
    # [...]
    if "active" in request.query_params:
        if "t" in request.query_params["active"].lower():
            request.query_params["active"] = True
        else:
            request.query_params["active"] = False

    if "sensitivity" in request.query_params:
        if "t" in request.query_params["sensitivity"].lower():
            request.query_params["sensitivity"] = True
        else:
            request.query_params["sensitivity"] = False
    # [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about defining `keys = ['active', 'sensitivity']` and then do

```
for key in keys:
    obj = request.query_params.get(key)
    if obj is None:
        continue
    request.query_params[key] = "t" in obj.lower()
```

or equivalently,

```
for key in keys:
    obj = request.query_params.get(key)
    if obj is not None:
        request.query_params[key] = "t" in obj.lower()
```

Comment: Making a list of keys is great idea. I have to change "t" to True if  t is in request.query_params[key] else to False. But I got the idea. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user8140238 There is no "idea to get": my answer is not a pseudocode, it is a fully functional python code. You miss something:  `"t" in obj.lower()` is a boolean,  exactly `True` in case `"t"` is in `obj.lower()`. When you do `a = 2`, `a` becomes `2` isn't it ? Idem, when you do `a = True` <=> `a = 't' in obj.lower()`. Put differently, doing `True if "t" in obj.lower() else False` is a clear signal of musunderstanding of how boolean assigment work in general.

Comment: Any question/problem [@user8140238](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8140238/user8140238) ? Why this unacceptation ?

Answer (score 1):

```py
def serialize_boolean_field(request, param_key):
    """changing Boolean field text into python Boolean(True/False) if exist"""
    obj = request.query_params.get(param_key)
    if obj is None:
        request.query_params[param_key] = True if "t" in obj.lower() else False
```

Comment: `True if condition else False` can be optimized.

Comment: can you suggest? @KlausD. edited anyway :)

Comment: In python, we do `obj is None` to check that `obj` is None. As such, what happens if `obj` is `""` ?

Comment: @keepAlive my bad, fixed :)

Comment: `True if condition else False` -> `condition`

Comment: Especially, `obj.lower() == "t"` is not like `"t" in obj.lower()`